# Calling an AllJoyn property from Java causes a AnnotationBusException

Tags: java, android, alljoyn, android-studio-2.3

I'm struggling with using properties in AllJoyn.  I'm new to AllJoyn but not to programming.  I have a provider written C++ and I add my properties using

```
status = m_Description->AddProperty("ServerName", "s", 1)
```

After that call status equals ER_OK.

I define my Java Property in the interface as the following:

```
 @BusProperty(annotation = BusProperty.ANNOTATE_EMIT_CHANGED_SIGNAL)
 String getServerName() throws BusException;
```

However, when I try to use the property on in Java (Android using Android Studio) by making the call as:

```
String str = proxyInterface.getServerName();
```

I keep getting the following exception:

> 04-07 10:11:45.592 26005-26005/com.wolfecomputerservices.cumulus
>   W/System.err: org.alljoyn.bus.AnnotationBusException: field public
>   static transient volatile
>   com.android.tools.fd.runtime.IncrementalChange
>   com.wolfecomputerservices.cumulus.ui.Android.Communication.AllJoyn.Objects.ServerData.$change
>   of class
>   com.wolfecomputerservices.cumulus.ui.Android.Communication.AllJoyn.Objects.ServerData
>   does not annotate position 04-07 10:11:45.592
>   26005-26005/com.wolfecomputerservices.cumulus W/System.err:     at
>   org.alljoyn.bus.Signature.structTypes(Signature.java:71) 04-07
>   10:11:45.592 26005-26005/com.wolfecomputerservices.cumulus
>   W/System.err:     at
>   org.alljoyn.bus.Signature.classTypeSig(Signature.java:170) 04-07
>   10:11:45.592 26005-26005/com.wolfecomputerservices.cumulus
>   W/System.err:     at
>   org.alljoyn.bus.Signature.typeSig(Signature.java:117) 04-07
>   10:11:45.592 26005-26005/com.wolfecomputerservices.cumulus
>   W/System.err:     at
>   org.alljoyn.bus.InterfaceDescription.getOutSig(InterfaceDescription.java:511)
>   04-07 10:11:45.592 26005-26005/com.wolfecomputerservices.cumulus
>   W/System.err:     at
>   org.alljoyn.bus.InterfaceDescription.addMembers(InterfaceDescription.java:386)
>   04-07 10:11:45.592 26005-26005/com.wolfecomputerservices.cumulus
>   W/System.err:     at
>   org.alljoyn.bus.InterfaceDescription.create(InterfaceDescription.java:199)
>   04-07 10:11:45.592 26005-26005/com.wolfecomputerservices.cumulus
>   W/System.err:     at
>   org.alljoyn.bus.ProxyBusObject.addInterface(ProxyBusObject.java:115)
>   04-07 10:11:45.592 26005-26005/com.wolfecomputerservices.cumulus
>   W/System.err:     at org.alljoyn.bus.ProxyBusObject.getProperty(Native
>   Method) 04-07 10:11:45.592
>   26005-26005/com.wolfecomputerservices.cumulus W/System.err:     at
>   org.alljoyn.bus.ProxyBusObject.access$400(ProxyBusObject.java:35)
>   04-07 10:11:45.592 26005-26005/com.wolfecomputerservices.cumulus
>   W/System.err:     at
>   org.alljoyn.bus.ProxyBusObject$Handler.invoke(ProxyBusObject.java:274)
>   04-07 10:11:45.592 26005-26005/com.wolfecomputerservices.cumulus
>   W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.invoke(Proxy.java:397)
>   04-07 10:11:45.592 26005-26005/com.wolfecomputerservices.cumulus
>   W/System.err:     at $Proxy4.getServerRunning(Unknown Source) 04-07
>   10:11:45.592 26005-26005/com.wolfecomputerservices.cumulus
>   W/System.err:     at
>   com.wolfecomputerservices.cumulus.ui.Android.Communication.AllJoyn.Interfaces.ICumulusImpl.IsRunning(ICumulusImpl.java:24)
>   04-07 10:11:45.593 26005-26005/com.wolfecomputerservices.cumulus
>   W/System.err:     at
>   com.wolfecomputerservices.cumulus.ui.Android.Communication.AllJoyn.Handlers.BusHandler.processMessage(BusHandler.java:276)
>   04-07 10:11:45.593 26005-26005/com.wolfecomputerservices.cumulus
>   W/System.err:     at
>   com.wolfecomputerservices.cumulus.ui.Android.Abstracts.PauseHandler.handleMessage(PauseHandler.java:75)
>   04-07 10:11:45.593 26005-26005/com.wolfecomputerservices.cumulus
>   W/System.err:     at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 04-07
>   10:11:45.593 26005-26005/com.wolfecomputerservices.cumulus
>   W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194) 04-07
>   10:11:45.593 26005-26005/com.wolfecomputerservices.cumulus
>   W/System.err:     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5567) 04-07
>   10:11:45.593 26005-26005/com.wolfecomputerservices.cumulus
>   W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>   04-07 10:11:45.593 26005-26005/com.wolfecomputerservices.cumulus
>   W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>   04-07 10:11:45.593 26005-26005/com.wolfecomputerservices.cumulus
>   W/System.err:     at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:955)
>   04-07 10:11:45.593 26005-26005/com.wolfecomputerservices.cumulus
>   W/System.err:     at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:750)
>
> Note:  I do have a method that has a return value of ServerData. 
>   However, that is not what I'm calling when this error occurs. I
>   sucessfully make that call long before trying to call the method. It
>   is the method call that causes this exception. However, I do have
>   ServerData annotated with @Position(x) for each field number 0-4.

What am i doing wrong?

Update:

ServerData from C++ Provider

```
class ServerData {
    public:
        const char* Id;
        const char* Name;
        const char* Version;
        const char* MachineName;
        const char* BaseUrl;
    };
```

From Java Consumer:

```
public class ServerData {
    @Position(0)
    @Signature("s")
    public String Id;

    @Position(1)
    @Signature("s")
    public String Name;

    @Position(2)
    @Signature("s")
    public String Version;

    @Position(3)
    @Signature("s")
    public String MachineName;

    @Position(4)
    @Signature("s")
    public String BaseURL;
}
```

UPDATE:  Unfortunately, that doesn't seem possible for me to switch version of gradle.  I'm currently on 2.3.1; switching to 2.1.3 causes the following error during build (I've tried all the suggestions listed):

Unfortunately, that doesn't seem possible for me to switch version of gradle.  I'm currently on 2.3.1; switching to 2.1.3 causes the following error during build: 
Error:org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultTaskInputs$TaskInputUnionFileCollection cannot be cast to org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DefaultConfigurableFileCollection
Possible causes for this unexpected error include:

- Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)
  Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)
- The state of a Gradle build process (daemon) may be corrupt. Stopping all Gradle daemons may solve this problem.
  Stop Gradle build processes (requires restart)
- Your project may be using a third-party plugin which is not compatible with the other plugins in the project or the version of Gradle requested by the project.

In the case of corrupt Gradle processes, you can also try closing the IDE and then killing all Java processes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that the ServerData fields in question are public and that there is no typo in any of the @Position(n) annotations that you have specified immediately before each public field.

**UPDATE:**

I have seen this Annotation error message when building in Android Studio with gradle 2.2.3. However, when I went back to using gradle 2.1.3 the annotation error went away.

Check your top level build.gradle file. Update its classpath dependency to be...

> dependencies {
>       classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.3'
>   }

**UPDATE 2:**

Another workaround, if you need to build in Android Studio with gradle > 2.1.3, is to disable Android Studio's "instant run" feature. The instant run feature is automatically adding two **public** static fields to classes (i.e. it is adding the $change field and the serialVersionUID field).

The AllJoyn java-binding's processing of the Position annotations (which is done via reflection) does not currently account for these two fields being added by the compiler. This will be handled better by AllJoyn in its upcoming 16.10a maintenance release).

To disable "instant run", do the following within Android Studio...

> Open the Settings or Preferences dialog.
>   Navigate to Build, Execution, Deployment > Instant Run.
>   Uncheck the "Enable Instant Run to hot swap/resource changes on deploy" checkbox.

Comment: I hear what you are saying.  However, as I noted, ServerData has nothing to do with the call to the property.  It doesn't use that structure and in fact, the call that does use ServerData works perfectly fine long before the call the the property is called.

Comment: Can you provide the interface definition and the ServerData definition with the alljoyn bus annotations?

Comment: You might look at Android properties sample (https://cgit.allseenalliance.org/core/alljoyn.git/tree/alljoyn_java/samples/android?h=RB16.04). While the contacts sample has a data class that uses the @Position annotation.

Comment: I've updated the original question with ServerData. I have looked at the properties examples; however, none of them (that I can find) show how to have a C++ provider and a Java consumer. Also, I re-iterate, if I leave ServerData unchanged and simple removed the call to the property (which does not use ServerData), I do not get the error. Can somebody explain to me why it would complain about ServerData on the call to the property when it doesn't use it; but, on the method that does, no error?

Comment: @Ed, I have updated my answer with a verified solution. I got the same error that you are talking about when I was testing the AllJoyn Contacts sample on Android (built in Android Studio with gradle 2.2.3). When I reverted from building with gradle 2.2.3 back to using the older 2.1.3, the annotation error went away. Gradle 2.2 added something to do with Annotation processing, perhaps this has some ill side-affect to java annotations relating how the alljoyn Position bus annotation is processed.

Comment: @Ed, I updated my answer again, with information about how Android Studio's "instant run" feature can cause the error you are experiencing, and how to disable "instant run". I have verified this solution works with the AllJoyn Contacts sample on Android.

Comment: That fixed the problem.  Thank you!  I know get another error, but I'll create a new thread for that one.